# Quick sort with partition not compiling

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, quicksort, partition

I've been trying to get this code to compile, but it doesn't seem to want the partition function to work.  Apparently it's something to do with the array but I can't figure out what it is.

Edit: I'm using the std::partition, not an original partition function.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 10000;
const int MIN_SIZE = 10;
```

Here's the quick sort:

```
//quick sort
void quickSort(int arr[], int first, int last, int size)
{
    if(last - first + 1< MIN_SIZE)
    {
        insertionSort(arr,size);
    }
    else
    {
        int pivotIndex = partition(arr, first, last);
        quickSort(arr, first, pivotIndex-1,size);
        quickSort(arr, pivotIndex+1,last,size);
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'partition(int*&, int&, int&)'
```

Thanks to anyone who can clear this up.  Everything except the partition fucntion seems to work fine.

Comment: The compiler error is not about the array. It's about the `partition` function itself. It's not even called, it's just compiler not being able to understand what function you are trying to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you've done `using namespace std;` above this code. In this case, `std::partition` is an algorithm designed to work with STL containers, not raw C-style arrays. Consider checking with the reference (for example, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)).

Unfortunately, you'll need to either find/write a partition algorithm that works with raw arrays, or migrate from `int arr[]` to something like `std::vector<int>`.

Otherwise, if `partition` is indeed another function in your code, please provide it as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try both of those.

Comment: @BenPerkins also see the latest edit of the answer, since it's merely a guessing game so far...

Comment: I'm using std::partition, I should have included more.

Comment: There's nothing that stops you from using a raw array with partition. https://ideone.com/VBDne1 Stole the example from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition and modified it to use a raw array.